# How to do randomised benchmarking for non-Clifford gates on Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit, randomised-benchmarking

For my summer research internship I'm looking to randomized benchmark (RB) *non*-Clifford gates for a single qubit. Since I found out that Qiskit ignis [allows for the RB of Clifford gates](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/randomized_benchmarking.ipynb), naturally I thought I'd start there. However, the Ignis RB module doesn't seem to allow the RB of non-Clifford gates, or at least it doesn't seem like there's a straightforward way to modify it for non-Clifford gates simulation.  I wondering if anyone has any idea as to what modifications I could be making, or if there's any modules out there that could help me with what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply: it's on the to-do list.

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02720) is a sneak peak of how it will be done.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up having to code my own from scratch! Also, does IBM run any funded summer research internship in the fields of QIT or QC for foreign undergraduates(in my case the UK) who would've finished their final year, with the absolute intention of doing a PhD in the same area?I know in the US they run one but it's only for US citizens. I know there's an IBM lab in Zurich but I can't seem to find any more info.